# Alternative to 'alias' in Linux, on machine that doesn't support alias?

Tags: linux, alias

I'm running some code on a fairly locked-down cluster. I'm still figuring out what I can and can't do on this machine (e.g. I can't edit my own .bashrc, but I can set up RSA authentication for SSH).

Anyway, it appears that the cluster has disallowed using `alias`. When I do `alias tinyName=/path/to/really_really_long_executable_filename`, typing the command `tinyName` gives `command not found`.

Assuming that `alias` is off limits, are there any alternatives to `alias` that allow me to avoid typing `/path/to/really_really_long_executable_filename` every time?

P.S. The machine that I'm running on is NERSC Carver, and I haven't yet found list of which Linux commands are off-limits on this cluster.

Comment: `alias` is a shell built-in command. What shell are you using (try running `ps` or `echo $SHELL`)?

Comment: Can you create a shell script in your homedir and make it executable?

Comment: The syntax of the `csh` alias command is the alias name and the command as 2 separate arguments with no `=` between them. Change that `=` to a space and see what happens.

Comment: If you can create a shell script as mentioned above you can save the path as a shell variable.

e.g.

    my_path=/some/very/long/path

Then access it using

$my_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from configuring your shell correctly, you can create alias "scripts" and put them in your `PATH`.  It's suboptimal, but might be appropriate for your target.

e.g.:

```
sudo sh -c "echo '/path/to/really_really_long_executable_filename' > /usr/local/bin/tinyname"
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/tinyname
```

Comment: Nice. I ended up using a symlink, but similar idea. Thanks! :)